# Device nodes randomly disappear in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, arch-linux, systemd

I use vanilla Arch Linux with systemd. I made a psot on the Arch BBS to no avail, so I'm posting here.

Problem description:

I've been on this install for more than a year and never had this issue. I first noticed it with my webcam first (it would randomly disappear from the file system as if I didn't have one, and I would have to reboot for it to temporarily reappear) but I realised it was a more general issue because many other devices, including a keyboard, a mouse, a USB cable etc. simply wouldn't work. When I boot up, there's a 5-10% possibility that those devices will work for a couple hours before they disappear, but in all other cases they don't work at all.

When I boot up, for a split second the message `Failed to listen on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.` appears on the screen.

When I poweroff, I usually get `watchdog did not stop!`

And some other times I get `shutdown waiting for process systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd` with a varying number of "systemd-udevd" processes.

I think all of those problems are linked, not only because they appear at the same time, but because `watchdog` and `rfkill` are both devices and `udev` is the device manager.

Hardware:

- Laptop: 81LW Lenovo IdeaPad L340-1
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700U with Rade
- GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Picasso

Further information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux --- 5.15.2-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT ---- x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ pacman -Q linux
linux 5.15.2.arch1-1
```

Outputs of lsusb, dmesg, etc. on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aqDs3X7q)

Things I've rule out:

- It's not a hardware issue. All of my devices work fine on another boot
- I don't think it's the kernel. I use both the main and lts kernels and the problem appears on both, I've also downgraded both to many different versions and the problem persists. Updated as well.
- I've also downgraded systemd along with various systemd packages and the problem persists

Even though I've downgraded systemd, I believe it's a udev issue. It's the device manager, and it has problems dying on shut down. Other than that, however, I'm completely lost. I've no idea how to even begin to troubleshoot this. I would appreciate some help because I need a reliable webcam on monday for a midterm and I'm kind of stressed out about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downgrading usually doesn't help, as that adds bugs rather than fixing them.  This has to be a hardware or kernel issue, you can't eliminate both of them, because nothing else affects this.  Your logs in pastebin are useless -- too short, not showing any relevant activity.  We need to see logs that show device activity.  If these are USB devices, try unplugging the device and plugging it back in a few seconds later.  Logs from when the device is plugged in and from immediately before it disappears would be useful.

Comment: It's a hardware problem. As the components heat up, they fail. From what you said, they all tie into the usb chipset.

Comment: @user10489
How can it be a hardware issue when everything works fine 100% of the time on another distro? I've tested it multiple times and never had a problem on it. And also, how can it be a kernel issue when it appears in both the lts and mainline kernels (the problem appeared on a later kernel version than lts, yet is still there when I use lts). This is why I think it's a systemd-udevd issue. Is my reasoning flawed?

Pastebin for when I plug in and out a USB keyboard: https://pastebin.com/cP5ZJ0CB

Comment: @Bib I thought it was a hardware issue at first too, but as I said above, everything works fine on another distro. I've tested it multiple times.

Comment: Without proper logs showing the errors causing the device to disappear and maybe kernel versions from the broken distro and the working distro, we can't guess what the problem is.  You need to determine the name of the device that is having problems and grep for it in your logs.

Comment: You say that "device nodes randomly disappear" but you have not even included in the question the names of the devices.